# Unable to reach gateway after successful arp

Tags: networking

I'm working on a Rocky Linux 8.5 host. I created an 802.3ad bonded interface with a dual port NIC using nmcli. However, I'm unable to ping the gateway. Looking at the traffic with tcpdump, I can see an ARP request from my host and an expected response from the gateway, but no additional traffic is seen (no outbound ICMP packets are seen).

Regardless of any issues with the network or gateway, I assume I should still see the outbound ICMP traffic? I'm guessing I don't see the ICMP traffic because of some odd internal routing issue? There is another interface on this host, but I don't see the ICMP traffic sent from that interface either. The default gateway, and lowest metric, is set on the bonded interface. What have I configured incorrectly? Any ideas or troubleshooting suggestions?

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.40.217 dev bond0 proto static metric 200 
default via 10.5.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 203 
10.5.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 10.5.0.114 metric 203 
192.168.40.216/29 dev bond0 proto kernel scope link src 1192.168.40.220 metric 200
```

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:01:13:e1:84:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.5.0.114/24 brd 10.5.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 170451sec preferred_lft 170451sec
    inet6 fe80::1aa3:74ff:fe0e:c393/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: enp4s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:21:bb:43:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: enp4s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:21:bb:43:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 00:11:21:bb:43:39
8: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:21:bb:43:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.40.220/29 brd 192.168.40.223 scope global noprefixroute bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7c95:91f0:f39e:f681/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Before checking if ICMP is sent, you have to check the network stack (rather than the interface) received the ARP reply. To check the system received the ARP answer: `ip neigh` or in real time: `ip monitor neigh`: is the state changing from PROBE to REACHABLE (or STALE) or to FAILED? FAILED  would mean a configuration problem with bonding, but I don't know much about LACP.

Comment: Yes, 'ip neigh show' returns 'FAILED' for the bond0 device. As far as I can tell, the aggregation looks good (/proc/net/bonding/bond0 looks happy). I tried to add a static ARP entry for the gateway, but 'ip neigh add' returns 'RTNETLINK answers: File exists'

Comment: ip neigh replace (instead of add). but this won't fix the fact that you can't receive traffic (but apparently can send).

Comment: It seems the issue was caused by the switch port configuration. A native VLAN was set and that VLAN was also allowed as a tagged VLAN (removing the VLAN as a permitted tag resolved the behavior - Juniper). I don't know if this was an interop issue or an issue that I don't understand. The host wasn't tagging the traffic and I'm still not certain why the gateway's ARP response was captured by tcpdump but discarded by the host.